# Configuring relationships between non-PK columns in database-first EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to configure relationships between entities in EF Core 6, using an existing database as a starting point. I'm running into problems when the joins between tables are not between primary key columns. I scaffolded the C# classes automatically, so there may be problems caused by naming column renaming and mapping that I'm not sure exactly where I'm getting lost.

For example, I'm defining the relationships between the Employees and the Trips they've taken. The relevant tables/columns in SQL Server look like the following:

```
trips
    trip_id (PK)
    trip_employee_id
    ...

employees
    employee_key (PK)
    valid_date
    invalid_date
    employee_id
    ...
```

One thing to note is that employee_id is actually not a unique identifier within employees, but the combination of employee_id + invalid_date = NULL is. So the following query would be a join between them, assuming we want the most up-to-date info on the associated employee:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.trips t
INNER JOIN dbo.employees e
    ON t.trip_employee_id = e.employee_id
    AND e.invalid_date = NULL
```

I'm using DataAnnotations as much as I can, so my C# classes look like the following:

```cs
namespace Models
{
    [Table("trips")]
    public partial class Trip
    {
        [Column("trip_id")]
        [Key]
        public int TripId { get; set; }

        [Column("trip_employee_id")]
        public string TripEmployeeId { get; set; }

        // Other columns below
    }

    [Table("employees")]
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Column("employee_key")]
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }

        [Column("valid_date", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime ValidDate { get; set; }

        [Column("invalid_date", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? InvalidDate { get; set; }

        [Column("employee_id")]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        // Other columns below
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this within EF Core, with or without DataAnnotations? And automatic filtering on invalid_date also isn't necessary, just a nice to have, since I assume I could configure a 1-Many relationship from trips to employees and then just filter on employees where invalid_date = NULL.

The main question is just whether relationships are possible to configure when neither the principal or dependent entities link on the PK.

Comment: Do you want foreign key to reference a property(trip_employee_id) other than the primary key(trip_id)?You could use the Fluent API to configure the [principal key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#principal-key) property for the relationship.

Comment: @xing-zou Yes, but as part of the principal key documentation it says the following: "The property that you configure as the principal key will automatically be setup as an alternate key (see Alternate Keys for more information)." I was under the impression that an alternate key had to be unique - in my case employee_id is not unique within the employees table.